# Laravel usando AJAX (JSON) funciona pero solo me muestra el primer resultado

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

básicamente lo dicho en el título, el código funciona pero solo me lanza el primer resultado, habiendo más resultados en la BBDD. Esto es el código del controlador:

```
function action(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if($query != '') {
            
            //       o tambien     $data = casas::where('ciudad', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            $data = DB::table('casas')
                    ->where('ciudad', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orWhere('precio', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->get();
        } else {
            $data = DB::table('casas')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->get();
        }
        $total_row = $data->count();
        if($total_row > 0) {
            foreach($data as $row){
                $casas = '<tr>' . '<td>'.$row->ciudad.'</td>' . '<td>'.$row->precio.'</td>' . '</tr>';
            }
        } else {
            $casas = '<tr> <td align="center" colspan="5">No se encontraron datos</td></tr>';
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data' => $casas,
            'total_row' => $total_row
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Y esto es el script que uso en la vista:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    fetch_customer_data();
    function fetch_customer_data(query = '') {
      $.ajax({
          url:" {{ route('busca_search.action') }}",
          method:'GET',
          data:{query:query},
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(data)
          {
              $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
              $('#total_records').text(data.total_row);
          }
      })  
    }
    $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function() {
        var query = $(this).val();
        fetch_customer_data(query);
    });
});
</script>
```

El resultado de este código en pantalla es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver cuenta bien, es decir en la BBDD habría 3 casas de Almeria, pero solo me muestra el primer resultado, no me muestra las 3 que es lo que yo quisiera.

Agradecería mucho si me pudierais ayudar puesto que he probado ya varias cosas sin resultado óptimo.

Edito, gracias a @Benito-B el código ya realiza la función que deseaba, cito su respuesta;

Es normal que solo muestre un resultado, puesto que en $casas siempre estás machacando el valor con el siguiente... así solo te quedarás con el último. Lo que necesitas es hacerle un `$casas .= '<tr>' . '<td>'.$row->ciudad.'</td>' . '<td>'.$row->precio.'</td>' . '</tr>';`, es decir CONCATENAR el texto ahí, no reemplazarlo!

Comment: Es normal que solo muestre un resultado, puesto que en `$casas` siempre estás *machacando* el valor con el siguiente... así solo te quedarás con el último. Lo que necesitas es hacerle un `$casas .= '<tr>' . '<td>'.$row->ciudad.'</td>' . '<td>'.$row->precio.'</td>' . '</tr>';`, es decir **CONCATENAR** el texto ahí, no reemplazarlo!

Comment: @Benito-B Muchas gracias. Sin más que decir.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en tu controlador, en como preparas los datos que vas a devolver en el *JSON*:

```
function action(Request $request) 
{
...

foreach($data as $row) {
    $casas = '<tr>' . '<td>'.$row->ciudad.'</td>' . '<td>'.$row->precio.'</td>' . '</tr>';
            }
...
}
```

Aunque indicas que solo recibes el primer resultado, en realidad recibes el último. El dato que lee cada iteración del `foreach` reescribe al anterior.
Hay que sustituir

```
$casas = '<tr>'...
```

por

```
$casas .= '<tr>'...
```

En general, para hacer *debug*, en un problema como éste, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

**1. En la parte cliente.**
Comprobar la respuesta que recibes a tu llamada.
Dentro del bloque:

```
success:function(data)
{
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_row);
}
```

añadir:

```
console.log(data);
```

**2. En la parte servidor.**
Imprimir un log, con el contenido que estas tratando de devolver a la vista. En este caso como `$casas` guarda un string con todas las filas que esperas imprimir, puedes volcar su contenido directamente en el log de Laravel, terminado el *foreach*:

```
logger($casas);
```